# mongoose, find() data object exists when nothing is found in database

Tags: node.js, mongoose

i'm trying to make a code (!data) when theres no record found in collection, but data is always there, so i dont know how to handle this. this is my code:

```
UserModel.find({username: request.body.username}, function(error, data)
{
    if(error)
        console.log(error);

    if(data)
    {
        response.render('index',
        {
            'Title': Title,
            'result': data
        });
        mongoose.connection.close();
    }

    else
    {
        console.log('not found');
    }
});
```

data is always there, the 'not found' is not triggering even if there's nothing found in the database, i made the JSON.stringify() to see how is it returning, but its just [], i dont know what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your `find` returns empty array, It might have some inherited object properties.

You should change your `if(data)` to `if(data.lenght > 0)`.